# Переход по внешней ссылке в WebView osx Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, webview, cocoa

Добрый день, "пишу" свое первое приложение на Swift.

Есть WebView где я открываю сайт:

```
let defaultURL = "https://yandex.ru"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.EasyW.frameLoadDelegate = self
    self.EasyW.policyDelegate = self
    self.EasyW.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: defaultURL)!))

}
```

Все работает хорошо, но при клике по внешней ссылке, ничего не происходит( 
Каким образом можно открывать внешнюю ссылку в дефолтном браузере?

Answer (score 2):

Назначьте ваш контроллер делегатом для webView

Objective-c:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
if ([request.URL isEqual:_url]) {
    return YES;
}else{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
    return NO;
}
```

}

На Swift, примерно так, пожалуй:

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if(!(request.URL!.isEqual((NSURL(string: url)!)))){
        //Если это url не дефолтный (с которого мы запускаем webView),
        //то открыть через safari
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(request.URL!);
        return false;
    }else{
        //Открыть страницу в webView
        return true
    }
}
```

**UPD:**

```
    let url = "https://yandex.ru/"
    func webView(sender: WebView!,
               didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame frame: WebFrame!){
       if(!(webView.mainFrameURL.isEqual(url))){
        NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURL(NSURL(string:webView.mainFrameURL)!)
       }
     }
```

Comment: Не обратил внимание, что OS X, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ, но Xcode ругается на:        if(!(webView.mainFrameURL.isEqual(url))){
на переменную url

Comment: @Hulwer добавил объявление переменой, попробуйте

Comment: теперь в браузере открываются все запросы которые идут внутри WebView которые не равны строго https://yandex.ru/

Comment: А мне надо что бы при клике) Данный делегат обрабатывает все запросы) А мне исключительно те которые при клике)

Comment: @Hulwer а в каких случаях вы хотите открывать ссылку во внешнем браузере?

Comment: допустим на сайте yandex.ru - есть ссылка yandex.ru/test1 - она должна и открывается внутри WebView без проблем, но допустим есть ссылка на google.com - при клике по ней ничего не происходит, а мне надо что бы она открывалась в браузере)